# Show dialog when drawer is pressed

Tags: flutter, drawer, flutter-alertdialog

I am trying to make an alert dialog box when drawer is pressed, but don't know why it doesn't work.

```
 drawer: Drawer(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple),
                    accountName: Text("Aman Nafiz",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                    accountEmail: Text("amannafiz@gmail.com",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                    currentAccountPictureSize: Size.fromRadius(28),
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        size: 19,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.add_box),
                title: Text(
                  "Add Quotes",
                ),onTap:(){setState(() {
                   showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                              title: Text("Write the Quote and Authors name."),
                              content: TextFormField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 8,
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5)))),
                              ),
                            ));

                });} ,
              ),
```

Comment: you don't need to use `setState`. Also, please specify what is not working. Did you get any error?

Comment: Ok, Well when i press the ListTile in the drawer a AlertDialogBox was supposed to pop out But the AlertDialogBox isn't showing or popping out even after pressing it.

Comment: any exxception?